# how to show % label on geom_bar() plot in R when y-axis is shown in % of total instead of value

Tags: r, charts, ggplot2, percentage, geom-text

when use ..prop.. to show percentage in R bar plot, is there a way to show text label on top of the bars in percentage?

```
mpg%>% ggplot(aes(x=manufacturer,y=..prop..,group=1))+geom_bar()
```

Comment: Perhaps add `+ scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())`

Comment: thanks akrun. I actually meant the text label on top of the bars.

Comment: `geom_text()` or `geom_label()`

Comment: i'm puzzles on what to pass into geom_text().
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'prop' not found